# Having trouble with inequalities with rational numbers

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove a that if y, a rational number, is greater than zero, then y is not equal to zero.  I've identified two theorems that I think will be useful, in particular, `Qlt_not_eq` and `QOrder.neq_sym`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the `QOrder.neq_sym` theorem.  It seems that I can't pass it arguments with the "Check" tactic.  For example, when I try doing:

```
Check (QOrder.neq_sym y 0)
```

It gives me an error, and I'm not sure why.

```
Require Import QArith.
Require Import QOrderedType.

Theorem test : forall (x y : Q),
    y > 0 -> ~ y == 0.
Proof.
    intros.
    (* This works OK *)
    Check QOrder.neq_sym.  
    (* But this gives me an error *)
    Check (QOrder.neq_sym y 0).
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to use the `QOrder.neq_sym` theorem, or any other suggestions on how to make progress on this proof that I might be overlooking.

Comment: Does `Check (@QOrder.neq_sym y 0).` work?  (Hypothesis: implicit arguments)

Comment: Indeed it needs to take the proof.

Comment: I verified that I am able to do `Check (@QOrder.neq_sym y 0)`, but I'm still not able to use that within a rewrite tactic. Can you explain what you mean when you say that it needs to take the proof?

Comment: You can use `About QOrder.neq_sym` to have more information about `QOrder.neq_sym`. With that command, you can see that `x` and `y` are implicit arguments, i.e. they are supposed not to be given by the user, but rather inferred from the remaining argument, the proof that `~ 0 == y`. To use that lemma, `apply` it rather than trying to `rewrite` it (see @ejgallego's answer).

Comment: intros Q y Hy C; apply Qlt_not_eq in Hy; apply Hy, Qeq_sym, C.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be very useful for you but an alternative is to use the mathematical components library; in this setting theorems are stated for abstract algebraic structures, of which rational numbers are indeed an instance.

You have many theorems that state what you want in this case, including the direct one:

```
lt0r_neq0 (R : numDomainType) (x : R), 0 < x -> x != 0
```

Your original goal can be proved with:

```
Theorem test (y : Q) : y > 0 -> ~ y == 0.
Proof. now intros y_gt0; apply QOrder.neq_sym, Qlt_not_eq. Qed.
```